# Computing a limit involving integration

Tags: limits

[image: Question]

The value for $S$ is $3π+4\lambda\pi√3$

The only method to compute a limit that I have learnt is to take the numerator and denominator with highest power and then remove all the other terms. By that method the answer should be $\frac{1}{3√3}$

Can somebody help me in computing the limit?

Comment: Have you computed a value for $h$?

Comment: No. I know how to compute limit for 1/h which has to be 1/3.

Comment: It looks to me like $h$ might depend on $\lambda$, in order to make the limit $4 \pi$

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more.I have never studied limits of any kind except dividing by the variable with largest power which obviously isn't applicable in this case.

Comment: Dividing the variable with largest power is exactly what you need to do here!  But note the limit has $h$ in it, so the question wants you to compute $h$ first, and then the limit should be straightforward for you.  The question gives you enough to calculate the value of $h$, which isn't tidy but is doable, then you can express $S/hs$ in terms of $\lambda$, and take the limit in the way you're used to.

Comment: Okay, can you tell me how to calculate limit of h? Second how did you know h has to be calculated first?

Comment: It's not the limit of h that's of interest just yet, but the value of h. You can calculate this by finding the y coordinate of the centroid of the given region.  You know h has to be calculated because the limit depends on it! You can't find the limit unless you know what all the quantities in it are.

Comment: Well y-coordinate of the centroid is just $1/2 \int y^2$ which is kind of already given.

Comment: That's not all, there's a factor you're missing in there

Comment: Ohh yes $\frac{1/2 \int y^2}{\int y }$. Now it is complete, I would be able to find the limit?

Comment: Yes, find the value of that in terms of $\lambda$ first, then it should become clear.

Comment: Yes, done thank you.